# Wix toolset - hide/show controls - why both are needed?

Tags: wix

I saw many examples like this:

```
<Control Id="contorlId" Type="CheckBox" property="PROP1" CheckBoxValue="1">
       <Condition Action="hide">A</Condition>
       <Condition Action="show">NOT A</Condition>
</Control>
```

Why is it required to set both conditions? (In most/all cases the 'hide' condition is the NOT of the 'show' condition.

If the condition is more complex, such as the following:

```
<Control Id="contorlId" Type="CheckBox" property="PROP1" CheckBoxValue="1">
       <Condition Action="hide">    A AND B AND C AND D AND E</Condition>
       <Condition Action="show">NOT(A AND B AND C AND D AND E)</Condition>
</Control>
```

this redundancy can easily lead to bugs.

Is there a way to write this without having to specify both 'show' and 'hide' conditions, but keeping the same functionality?

Thanks

Ofer Presente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasonable question. The answer is here in your question:

> (In most/all cases the 'hide' condition is the NOT of the 'show' condition.

If you assume the answer is "most" (and not "all") then the current design supports the case when the conditions are different... at the cost of extra verbosity.

Is this something the toolset could handle for you? Very likely. It is an open source project, so you could jump into the community and work with them to implement such a feature.

Comment: Thanks Rob. In my code, the 'hide' condition is ALWAYS the NOT of the 'show' condition.

Perhaps the design would make more sense to me if I saw an example where conditions are different.

Comment: @OferPresente as a language designer, I have to make choices without omniscience. Should the language provide flexibility with additional complexity or simplicity with restrictions? Trust me, you'd be mighty frustrated if the language didn't allow you to have separate conditions when you needed it. Now, over the years, I've been slowly getting smarter at ways to expose simplicity _and_ still provide flexibility with complexity when needed. There is some of that in WiX v4 and much more planned for WiX v5.